# Adding custom behavior to Clojure's sequences

Tags: clojure, polymorphism, abstraction

Part of what's so powerful about Clojure is that all the core data-types implement the same sequence abstraction: clojure.lang.ISeq.

This means that functions like "first", "concat", "cons", "map", "rest", etc work generically on all of those data-types.

My question is this: how can I add my own custom function into the mix, and have it work for all the types that extend from ISeq?

One first attempt was to define my own protocol, then "(extend-type clojure.lang.ISeq ...", but that doesn't work (it compiles but doesn't add the behavior to the actual types). Another idea was to write a macro that does an "extend-type" explicitly on all the Clojure types (PersistentHashMap, PersistentList, etc), but that seems kludgey.

Is there any elegant/idiomatic way to do this? Multimethods perhaps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do?

If you're trying to add behaviour to existing types: either write normal functions that deal with seqs or use multimethods or `extend` to do what you want.

Also, something to note is that most Clojure "sequence" types (vectors, sets, maps) are not in themselves sequences (they do not implement `clojure.lang.ISeq`), so you have to do more than just add to `clojure.lang.ISeq` if you wish to support them.

Comment: Don't know why this got downvoted. This is the correct answer. If you want to write a function that acts on seqs, just write a function that acts on seqs, and call (seq arg) in that function to convert any sequable collection passed in to a seq.

Answer (score 3):

There's an IBM Developerworks article by Stuart Sierra titled [Solving the Expression Problem with Clojure 1.2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-clojure-protocols/) that might provide insights and an answer to your question.

It uses protocols to define a group of functions on several data types, and uses `extend` to extend existing classes (data types) so they can use these functions. That might not be exactly what you want, but it could be one way of solving your problem.

It also shows you how you could define custom data types (using `defrecord` and `deftype`) that implement existing protocols / interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to write your new functions using *existing generic Clojure functions* that handle the different data types correctly.

Examples of such generic functions:

- `into` appends items to a collection of any type
- `empty` returns an empty collection of the same type as it's parameter

Then you can write your own generic function that exploits these, e.g.:

```
(defn take-every-other [coll]
  (into 
    (empty coll)
    (map first (partition 2 coll))))

 (take-every-other [1 2 3 4 5 6])
 => [1 3 5]

 (take-every-other {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4})
 => {:a 1, :c 3}
```

If you still need more generic function capability, you can always dive into the Clojure source to see how these functions are written.